How to fetchcontent_declare() properly and also target link these libraries?
I am trying to get some libraries with FetchContent_Declare(), however I dont know if my library names in the target_link_libraries() method are right (How can I know it) and also why I am getting this error below:
  Performing download step (git clone) for 'glslang--populate'
  Cloning into 'glslang--src'...
  fatal: invalid reference: master
  CMake Error at glslang--subbuild/glslang--populate-prefix/tmp/glslang--populate-gitclone.cmake:61 (message):
    Failed to checkout tag: 'master'
  

This is my CMakelists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

project(foo)

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
    glslang-${glslang_VERSION}
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang.git
    GIT_TAG ${glslang_VERSION}
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
    SYSTEM
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(glslang-${glslang_VERSION})

if(NOT glslang-${glslang_VERSION}_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(glslang-${glslang_VERSION})
endif()


set(spirv_cross_VERSION "vulkan-sdk-1.3.290.0")

FetchContent_Declare(
    spirv_cross-${spirv_cross_VERSION}
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Cross.git
    GIT_TAG ${spirv_cross_VERSION}
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/spirv_cross-${spirv_cross_VERSION}-src/spirv_cross
    PATCH_COMMAND git apply ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/patches/spirv-cross-${spirv_cross_VERSION}.diff
    UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1
    SYSTEM
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(
    spirv_cross-${spirv_cross_VERSION}
)

FetchContent_Declare(
    spirv_tools
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Tools.git
   
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(spirv_tools)



add_library( ${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)

target_include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}

    PRIVATE
    ${glslang-${glslang_VERSION}_SOURCE_DIR}

    PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/spirv_cross-${spirv_cross_VERSION}-src/
)

target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    glslang::glslang
    glslang::glslang-default-resource-limits
    glslang::SPIRV
    spirv-cross-core
    spirv-cross-glsl
    SPIRV-Tools-static
    SPIRV-Tools-opt
)

As far as I know I don`t need find_package method, in those there are those library names I could use in the target_link_libraries. I am a bit mixed up where I can get the library names or it is simply the name in the FetchContentDeclare method?
Any help is appreciated!

Call to FetchContent_MakeAvailable is effectively add_subdirectory call, which executes a subproject's CMakeLists.txt. That is, in your main project you could use targets created in the subproject. For determine which subproject's targets to use you could read the documentation, or examine the subproject's sources. E.g. the project https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang in gsglang/CMakeLists.txt defines the target gsglang (and in the following line it defines alias target glslang::glslang).

As for the error fatal: invalid reference: master it is about absence of master branch in the subproject. If you look into the repo, you could find that it default branch is named as main.
